# problem with using polish keyboard with synergy 1.4.2

Tags: windows-7, synergy

I installed synergy on Windows 7 as server and on Windows Vista as client.
On both I can use polish keyboard using local keyboard.
When I am using remote keyboard via synergy polish characters are not working (I mean in example S + Alt Gr or S + left Alt + left ctrl)
I've used synergy about 1 year ago and I cannot recall that kind of problem so I think the problem is only in current version.
Searching through your web site and googled I found only identical problem 5 years ago with information that it was solved.

Please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 4):

Download on both systems beta version of synergy 1.4.8 and add on the server (Linux) section:

```
section: screens
    hunter:
    hunterpad:
        altgr = alt
end
```

On Windows 7 you'll no longer have problems with polish żółć ęśą źńŚ etc made by Altgr (right alt) on MS Word and other programs.

Comment: This! this should be accepted answer. What is enough actually is to add `altgr = alt` only on Windows machine screen. Works for both small and big national characters. Thank you!

Comment: today on two ubuntu 16.04 with synergy 1.6.2 I had same problem. For whatever reason the fix was to add "altgr = altgr".

Answer (score 0):

Synergy (currently) works by sending characters over the wire rather than key codes.  This means if there is no mapping for the Polish characters, Synergy won't know what to send over the wire to the other computer.  I think the only way around this is to add a mapping for each character to the Synergy source code, or wait for the new version of Synergy which will hopefully use key codes instead.

Comment: After few days I will check my old configuration which still should exist. If I recall correctly it was working properly with polish characters. On both systems I am using the same keyboard (polish programmers) and I can write it properly using "local" keyboards